# Accessing another user's custom Calendar programatically

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I am working on an outlook plugin. I want to give my manager reviewer permission to see my custom calendar (not the main Outlook Calendar) which I create programmatically.

My manager should be able to view my custom calendar programmatically.

I have given reviewer permission to my manager.

As of now, I don't know of any way where he can directly access my custom calendar programmatically. My custom calendar is at the same level as the main calendar.

A code like the following will not solve my purpose.

```
Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oNS.CreateRecipient(userName); 
Outlook.MAPIFolder usersCalendarFolder = 
  (Outlook.MAPIFolder) oNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(oRecip, 
                Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar)
```

As this is to get my root calendar only.

And I dont want  to give reviewer permission on my root folder. i.e. just "**reviewer**" permission on the custom calendar.

Do we have a way to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 0):

Only Outlook's default folders for each item type can be accessed using GetSharedDefaultFolder.  If you need to share any other folder that you've created manually, you'll have to share your entire Mailbox so that they can open it as an additional Mailbox in their Outlook profile or add it as a separate account.